# How to add shadow only on the bottom View in react native Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, styles, shadow

I need to add a shadow only on the bottom of a component for and android device (expo reac native)

I get it always on the 4 sides.

```
list: {
        display: "flex",
        position: "relative",
        borderRadius: 5,
        margin: 10,

        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,

        elevation: 3,
    },
```

I am trying something like this in my styles but only seems to work: elevation and shadowColor, the rest of the shadow styles do not seem to do anything in my android emulator (maybe in ios it does)

Answer (score 0):

you are correct,
for android the only property available is `elevation`
rest all properties are ios only. you can check here [RN- shadow- props](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props)

For ios it will be very easy to add shadow at bottom by just passing

```
shadowOffset:{
height:-20 // whatever you wanna have
}
```

But for android, you need to have external packages for it to work like [rn-shadow-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-shadow-2)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to deal with that tutorial, but it doesn't seem helpful enough.